# Embed Facebook post auto height for width = 300px

Tags: facebook

I want to do embed facebook post into my website sidebar that have 300px

the problem is, the height of the iframe doesnt auto adjust correctly, sometimes it's lower that normal, and sometimes it's heighter than normal

is there a way to have the height of iframe embed code post automaticaly adjust for the content ?

thank you

Comment: It should more or less automatically do that, if you embed it via the JS SDK (and not the iframe version directly.)

Comment: it doesnt work, i set width to 300, it set 350

Comment: For the width, the documentation explicitly states that 350px is the minimum width. If you stuff that into a column that is only 300px wide, expect unexpected side effects …